# Javascript in SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

I created a SVG file contains 5 polygons, then I need to embed Javascript so 4 of the polygons' color changes to Red when mouseover, and when mouseout, the color changes to Green. I tried to write the code but it didn't work, what could be the problem? Thanks for help and tips!

```
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="26cm" height="24cm" viewBox="0 0 2600 2400" version="1.1" 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
  xmlns:xlink= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<script type="text/javascript">
<![CDATA[

document.getElementById("test").onmouseover = function(){changeColor()};

function changeColor() {
document.getElementById("test").style.color = "red";
}

document.getElementById("test").onmouseout = function(){changeColor()};

function changeColor() {
document.getElementById("test").style.color = "green";
}

]]>
</script>
<circle cx="1600" cy="700" r="600" fill="yellow" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
<ellipse id="test" cx="1300" cy="500" rx="74" ry="120" fill="blue" stroke="black"  stroke-width="3" onmouseover="javascript:red();" onmouseout="javascript:green();"/>
<ellipse id="test" cx="1850" cy="500" rx="74" ry="120"  fill="blue" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" onmouseover="javascript:red();" onmouseout="javascript:green();"/>
<rect id="test" x="1510" y="650" width="160" height="160" fill="blue" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" onmouseover="javascript:red();" onmouseout="javascript:green();"/>
<polygon id="test" points="1320,800 1370,1080 1820,1080 1870,800 1820,1000 1370,1000" name="mouth" fill="blue" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" onmouseover="javascript:red();" onmouseout="javascript:green();"/> 

</svg>
```

Comment: You can't reuse the same ID. You need to use a class instead and iterate through each by using a for loop and `.length`, applying the listeners to both. You'll also have to have different behavior for `onmouseover` and `onmouseout`

Comment: I'm new to Javascrip, could you please give me examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have various errors

1. you've two functions called `changeColor`, functions must have unique names
2. SVG does not use `color` to colour elements, instead it uses `fill` (and `stroke`).
3. `id` values must be unique, you probably want to replace `id` by `class` and then use `getElementsByClassName` instead of `getElementById`. If you do that you'll need to cope with more than one element though. I've not completed that part, you should try it yourself so you understand what's going on.

I've removed all but one id from my version so you can see it working on the left eye.

```js
document.getElementById("test").onmouseover = function(){changeColor()};

function changeColor() {
document.getElementById("test").style.fill = "red";
}

document.getElementById("test").onmouseout = function(){changeColor2()};

function changeColor2() {
document.getElementById("test").style.fill = "green";
}
```

```html
<svg width="26cm" height="24cm" viewBox="0 0 2600 2400" version="1.1" 
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
  xmlns:xlink= "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">

<circle cx="1600" cy="700" r="600" fill="yellow" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/>
<ellipse id="test" cx="1300" cy="500" rx="74" ry="120" fill="blue" stroke="black"  stroke-width="3"/>
<ellipse cx="1850" cy="500" rx="74" ry="120"  fill="blue" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
<rect x="1510" y="650" width="160" height="160" fill="blue" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" />
<polygon points="1320,800 1370,1080 1820,1080 1870,800 1820,1000 1370,1000" name="mouth" fill="blue" stroke="black" stroke-width="3"/> 

</svg>
```

Comment: You've got more than one bug is all.

Comment: I see it works (Run code snippet), however, it still not working after I did all changes. I also tried to wirte exact the same code as yours (for testing) and it's not working. How is this possible, I mean the code indeed work well in Run code snippet but then why it won't work when I run SVG file in my browser.

Answer (score 2):

For what you are doing I would recommend using pure CSS.

[Here is some working code.](http://jsfiddle.net/7pzsbzn3/)

```
svg:hover .recolor {
    fill: red;     
}
```

As you see, you can just use the :hover event in CSS to recolor the necessary elements. And set them to your default color (green), which will take effect when the user is not hovered.

Comment: Well in my opinion StackOverflow is about best practice, not completing an assignment. I would not choose to do what you are being asked with JS, is inefficient in terms of performance.